# Birt: CSS conditional in rptdesign

Tags: css, birt

I'am working on a report using Birt.

I need to display a border in a color depending on the sex of the person.

For exemple i use:

```
<property name="borderLeftColor">#05C1FF</property>
```

But I would like it to be conditional.

I have a JS function that gives me the color code.

```
getColorFromSexe((dataSetRow["Sexe"]))
```

Used with

```
<expression name="myBorderLeftColor" type="javascript">
    getColorFromSexe((dataSetRow["Sexe"]))
</expression>
```

I would like something like this  :

```
<expression name="myBorderLeftColor" type="javascript">
  getColorFromSexe((dataSetRow["Sexe"]))
</expression>
<property name="borderLeftColor">myBorderLeftColor</property>
```

Does anyone knows how to do something like this in a .rptdesign ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My question wasn't really smart.
I changed it for a switch case like code:

```
<structure>
  <property name="operator">eq</property>
  <expression name="testExpr" type="javascript">row["Sexe"]</expression>
  <simple-property-list name="value1">
    <value type="javascript">2</value>
  </simple-property-list>
  <property name="style">liseret_rose</property>
</structure>
```

It's working fine.